Windows OpenSSH access of UNC path appears limited to read only?
I have a windows machine (AWS instance) that can visit and mount a shared network drive (samba/linux).
When I am on the windows machine itself via RDP I can visit the path, mount it as a drive, make folders and make files via both explorer and powershell.
When I ssh into the windows machine I can visit the path, mount it as a drive, enumerate the folders, and read the files. But "access to path '' is denied." whenever I try to make a folder or file (mkdir/Set-Content/New-Item).
The same is true of other applications run via SSH that attempt the same operations through I imagine the c++ windows api. I get mkdir errors from Perforce when syncing.
I have tried searching for this but almost every result is based on how mapped drives aren't available over ssh as they are "session" specific.
I have tried and failed to reproduce the issue on the machine itself via RDP and powershell to make sure it wasn't powershell command specific.
I have verified the user/password being used to mount the drive has proper read/write access.
I have stored the credentials for the drive in the windows credential manager which I think is why the ssh connection can access the UNC path directly without mounting.
I have tried first mounting the UNC path to a drive letter and trying the ssh commands on the mounted drive instead. Same read only behavior happens.
I have tried setting the "EnableLinkedConnections" registry key as I originally assumed this is due to a mix of elevated vs non-elevated prompts
I would expect to have write access to this drive via ssh like I do via RDP especially when I mount it during the ssh session as all credentials seem to be lining up, but so far that doesn't seem to be the case.

I have voted to close as not about programming.

Fair enough, this originally stemmed from an issue while programming but I did whittle it down to non-programming and just kind of forgot.
